# Migrate Stripe checkout due to CSA regulations

Tags: javascript, python, stripe-payments

so in my last project i used the stripe api and created a stripe-button that opens a popup, using a code like this:

```
<form action="/charge" method="post">
<script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"
    class="stripe-button"
    data-key="{{ stripe_key }}"
    data-description="app"
    data-amount="500"
    data-image= "/static/payment_logo.png"
    data-locale="auto">
</script>
</form>
```

On the server side i have the endpoint to validate the transaction and i also save the stripe id for future payments:

```
    ...
    customer = stripe.Customer.create(
        email=current_user.email,
        source=request.form['stripeToken']
    )

    stripe.Charge.create(
        customer=customer.id,
        amount=500,
        currency='usd',
        description='Premium mode'
    )
    ...
```

Recently my team recieved a mail that some payments haven't been made due to the fact that our stipe implementation isn't in rule with the CSA regulations. The stipe migration page didn't help us that much since we didn't know what product exactly replaces our current implementation. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The stipe migration page didn't help us that much since we didn't know
>   what product exactly replaces our current implementation.

The replacement for your current implementation, referred to as the legacy version of Checkout, is actually just a new version of Checkout!

You can reference the following migration guide in Stripe's docs which has excellent side-by-side code comparisons for both the client and server:

https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/migration

The new version of checkout fully supports 3D Secure and is thus compliant with SCA regulations.